# how to break the words if comes before and after "-" using php?

Tags: php

I wanna separate the words which comes before and after the "-" using php. I am unable to separate the text  which carry space befor and after the "-".

```
<?php
$value="this | is : my , text - test , done > hello-hi";
$keywords = preg_split("/[,|:&>]+/", $value);
print_r($keywords);
?>
```

Answer m getting:
Array ( [0] => this [1] => is [2] => my [3] => text - test [4] => done [5] => hello-hi )

Answer I want will be like : 
Array ( [0] => this [1] => is [2] => my [3] => text [4]=>test [5] => done [6] => hello-hi )

Comment: `explode('-', $value, 2)` will separate the string into after the '-' and after it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: I am not getting the result as per i require after using explode also. @Pheagey

Comment: My bad, didn't read the whole thing. Did not see you wanted to break at all non alphabetical characters. Try this one: `str_word_count($string, 2)`. That will explode the entire string placing each word in a new array value. You will have to merge the last two items to get `hello-hi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could make a gruop and add one `OR` (`|`) to split words between the `-`.

`([,|:&>]+|\s+-\s+)` will split by `,|:&>` or a for one or more spaces followed by a `-` and followed by one or more spaces. This avoid strings/text like `hello-hi` to split in two elements.

```
$value="this | is : my , text - test , done > hello-hi";
$keywords = preg_split("/([,|:&>]+|\s+-\s+)/", $value);
print_r($keywords);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => this [1] => is [2] => my [3] => text [4] => test [5] => done  [6] => hello-hi )
```